# Remove attributes of object temporarily?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have an Object A and Object

```
public class A
{
  private String a;
  private String b;
  private Student student;

  //getter and setter 
}

private class Student
{
 private String x;
 private String y;
 private String z;
}
```

Suppose I have a two method that returns A

```
public A getPart1()
{
 return A;
}

public A getPart2()
{
 return A;
}
```

Now I want method getPart1() to return A object without Student object in it and method getPart2() to return B object with Student object in it. Any java or spring way to do so? Please help

Comment: Cant you just set A.Student object to null in getPart1() method before returning A?

Comment: You could add class B which inherits from A and contains member student. getPart1 would return the stored B instance and getPart2 would cast B to A and return.

Comment: `Suppose I have a two method that returns A` .. in which class this two methods are??

Answer (score 1):

Here what you are doing is creating `Student` Class `Objcet` with in A. So, Student is tightly Coupled with A. so, Every time when u try to return Object Of A then student object will automatically wrapped into it.

There are other way to achieve what you want by serialization. `trasient` Keyword Used. `transient` modifier tells the Java object `serialization` subsystem to exclude the field when serializing an instance of the class.

but here u  have not mentioned any `serialization` word so, Easiest woy to do that is as Follows......

```
  public A getPart1()
    {
     A obj_A; //Contains the Object Type A Class
     obj_A.setStudent(null); 
     return obj_A;
    }

    public A getPart2()
    {
     A obj_A; //Contains the Object Type A Class
     return obj_A;

    }
```

Comment: its a mistake but i have already mentioned the comment please check it out. I am predicting that obj_A Already have refrence to the object.. Thanks